# Php foreach multiple arrays with if condion

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to foreach multiple arrays with if condition, I have 3 arrays like below :

```
$contents = array('content1', 'content2', 'content3', 'content4');    
$types = array('pdf', 'pdf', 'txt', 'pdf');    
$links = array('link1', 'link2', 'link3');

foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {
            
            echo "$value<br>";
            
        if ($types[$key] == 'pdf') {
             echo "$links[$key]<br>";
        }

}
```

Output is like this  :
content1
link1
content2
link2
content3
content4

**Links array has 3 values,  others 4 .**
**I want if content type is pdf use link value there if not skip.
And i want output like below:**

content1
link1
content2
link2
content3
content4
link3

thanks for your help

Comment: can you change the structure of the array? if yes: you could change it to a multidimensional array.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are not the same length then you won't be able to use the key.  You could use another variable to keep track of the key needed in `$links` or you can advance the pointer of `$links` each time:

```
foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value<br>\n";
        
    if ($types[$key] == 'pdf') {
         echo current($links) . "<br>\n";
         next($links);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you need to skip forward the links array so you can do it by adding an else statement.
try this code

```
$contents = array('content1', 'content2', 'content3', 'content4');
$types = array('pdf', 'pdf', 'txt', 'pdf');
$links = array('link1', 'link2', 'link3');

$skip_links_array = 0;

foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {

    echo "$value<br>";

    if ($types[$key] == 'pdf') {
        echo $links[$key + $skip_type]."<br>";
    }else{
        $skip_type--;
    }

}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GcT2q)